# How to store post details and timestamp in database?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

I am building a small blog script with **CodeIgniter**, and want to store poster id and poster name in the `blogs` table in my database.

How should I do this: do I pass via sessions, like this?

```
$data = array (
   'posterid'  =>  $this->session->userdata('id')
);
```

Secondly, I also have a `date_posted` column in my table. How can I set it with the date posted in the view?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question so it focusses on the essence. This will keep the attention of the readers. Feel of course free to make edits yourself. It is not necessary to introduce yourself, or thank in advance... It is best to get to the essence and leave it at that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the poster id is a session you have got it correct

**Couple user guide links will be use full.**

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Model filename: **Post_model.php**

```
<?php

class Post_model extends CI_Model {

public function add_post() {

$data = array(
      'id' => $this->session->userdata('id'),
      'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
      'post' => $this->input->post('post')
);

$this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'posts');

}

public function edit_post() {

$data = array(
     'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
     'post' => $this->input->post('post')
);

$this->db->where('id', $this->session->userdata('id'));
$this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'posts');

}

}
```

**Controller:**

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

```
<?php
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('folder/post_model');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->load->helper('url');
      $this->load->helper('form');
   }

   public function index() {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('post', 'Post');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

         $this->load->view('common/header');
         $this->load->view('posts');
         $this->load->view('common/footer');

      } else {

         // $this->post_model->add_post();
         // Or
         // $this->post_model->edit_post();

         redirect('success-controller');

      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of form data, you would usually access the `$_POST` request.  In Codeigniter you can say:

```
$data =  array(
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the user who posted the blog, I assume you already have the login functionality and you're storing the user id in the session, you are correct that you should retrieve the logged in user's id from the session to associate it with the blog post, and to add the date_posted, when doing the insert, just use php to add the current time ie:

```
new DateTime()
```

and ensure you have a field for the user_id and date_posted in the blogs table